# changing file names in Google docs

Tags: google-docs

I have have a great amount of files in Google docs, a lot of them are named as this "name 0102030110". I want to change their name, e.g. as "eman 0102030110". There are in great number, to change the names manually takes a lot of time.
Can I replace in one step a word of the names, as described, to change every occurence of "name" in the names of the files by "eman"?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] Google Docs / Google Drive haven't a built-in feature that does that. One option is to use Google Apps Script, more specíficaly the Drive Service and the Advanced Drive Service. Another option is to use the Google Drive API (off-topic here). If you need further help, please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search for helpful questions and answers on this site as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: @Rubén thanks for your comment. I don't know what is the Google apps script